# Why do I get this Warning/Error?

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, warnings, uncaught-exception

I have placed together some code which converts strings into data, and then places the data into another textfield. Everything works fine, but when I run the program and tap the button with the IB Action that contains this code:

```
[InputData setStringValue:OutputString];
```

I get this error:

**Thread 1: Program Received Signal: "SIGABRT".**

And in the Output area in the bottom of Xcode I get this message:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData setStringValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x62507e0'

Why does this happen?
The warning tells me that:

Instance method -setStringValue' not found (return type defaults to id)

What is going on, I have looked over it and it seems like it should work. What am I doing wrong? Im only a beginner with Objective-C.

Thank you, anything is appreciated.

Comment: What type is your InputData? Does it have a setStringValue method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there is a category on NSData that includes a setStringValue method. The category implementation file is likely named something like NSData-extras.m. Ensure that file has been added to Xcode (and if already known to Xcode, is part of the Target being built).

Comment: That is correct, it is NSMutableData-AES.m How do I make it a Target that is being built? Or check that it is?

Comment: Right click on the Project files and choose Add Files to <program>. That dialog lets you choose what targets the file should be linked with. You may only have one target (that's pretty normal) which makes the choice a simple one ;)

Answer (score 2):

According to the debugger your *InputData* object is an instance of NSMutableData, which does not have a *setStringValue* method. Look through your code and confirm that you're calling the method on the object you're really trying to target.

Comment: That makes sense, but I know that the way it is currently set up is the method I want to target.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your InputData must be UITextField, try this:

```
[InputData setText:OutputString];
```

Comment: Thanks @Saran, I tried this but I didn't seem to work. It just gave a different type of error